# TCP: data on a half-closed connection

Tags: tcp

I'm implementing a TCP stack, and have encountered an issue with half-closed connections.

My implementation acts as the server side. A client establishes a connection, then sends some data, and then sends a "FIN" message. The server then acknowledges the data from the client, sends some data of its own, and only then closes its half of the connection (sends "FIN").

The problem is that the client does not acknowledge the data sent by the server on the half-closed connection, nor its final "FIN" message. According to netstat, the client is in state FIN_WAIT2. In an identical scenario in which the server does not send any data, things go smoothly.
The client in question is netcat, so I assume the problem is on my end :)

A screen shot is available [here](http://www.sites.google.com/site/filestorage1221/pcap.gif).
The actual PCAP file is available [here](http://www.sites.google.com/site/filestorage1221/PushAfterFin.pcap).

My question is, generally, should I expect ACKS for data sent on a half-closed connection; and, particularly, what am I doing wrong in the example above.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't know that it's a half-closed connection from the peer's point of view. The client may have completely closed the connection, in which case the port is in CLOSE_WAIT at your side and FIN_WAIT_2 at the peer, but the peer would send RSTs instead of ACKs to your sends. Your links download .exes, which could be viruses as far as I'm concerned. Is there another way to make them available?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 

I've updated the links - hopefully they'll display correctly now.

Comment: The last line in the screenshot is an ACK for your first PSH. Is there any more?

Comment: I left it alone for a few minutes, and nothing else happened. Also, the netcat client didn't finish running, i.e. didn't return the prompt.

Comment: What's the port state on both sides?

Comment: Well, the client (netcat) seems to be in FIN-WAIT-1, having sent its FIN and not having acked the server's FIN message.

The server is in LAST-ACK.

Comment: Hmm. LAST-ACK makes sense given your problem description and the capture. LAST-ACK should be very short-lived. I don't think I've ever even seen it. FIN-WAIT-1 means the peer hasn't seen your ACK yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the server should send ACK=2561 instead of 2562 in FIN/ACK?

Comment: I've just tried using 2561 instead of 2562. This produced similar results - the client repeating its [FIN,PSH,ACK] message, but with sequence number 2562 - so I believe 2562 is the right think to ack in the first place (the FIN counts as 1 byte).


EJP, I've made a mistake in my earlier reply. Netstat says that in the original question (acking 2562), the client is in FIN-WAIT-2. When using 2561, it is in FIN-WAIT-1.

Comment: Yes I was wrong: it should be 2562. Apparently the client doesn't want to ack your data for an unknown reason. You could try to retransmit your data and to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

FIN-WAIT-2 means it saw the ACK, so the sequence number must be correct, but it also means it didn't see the FIN in the same segment. If the FIN counts as 1 byte maybe the LEN should be 1?

Comment: I think "LEN" is not an actual field in the packet - it's just wireshark telling you how many bytes the tcp segment contains. FIN is a flag in the header and not an actual byte, so I think 0 is correct.

I agree with your assessment that the client is ignoring the fin though. The problem seems to start earlier, when it doesnt ACK any of the data sent before the fin. This was part of my original question - should I expect the client to ack this data, having already closed its side of the connection?

Comment: Yes you should expect ACKs for all data.